# Powershell string does not contain

Tags: string, powershell

I have some code that takes in a string,

```
Foreach($user in $allUsers){
    if($user.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains("example.com") -or $user.DisplayName.ToLower()) {
    } else {
        $output3 = $externalUsers.Rows.Add($user.DisplayName)
    }
}
```

Part of the `if` right after the `-or` I need to check if the string does not contain an @ sign. How can I check to see if the @ sign is missing?

Comment: `.Contains()` returns a boolean. Just check for `!($user.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains("@"))`?

Comment: Perfect! If you create this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are a million ways to do it, I would probably go for the following due to readability:

```
$user.DisplayName -inotmatch "@"
```

The `-match` operator does a regex match on the the left-hand operand using the pattern on the right-hand side.

Prefixing it with `i` make it explicitly case-**i**nsensitive, and the `not` prefix negates the expression

You could also do:

```
-not($user.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains("@"))
or
!$user.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains("@")
```

For simple wildcard text-matching (maybe you hate regex, what do I know?):

```
$user.DisplayName -notlike "*@*"
```

Or alternatively look for the substring with IndexOf;

```
$user.DisplayName.IndexOf("@") -eq (-1)
```

Comment: I like the clearest way with -inotmatch.